# Chrome serving resource from cache when it is not present in cache-manifest

Tags: html, cache-manifest

I am playing around with HTML 5 cache manifests, and I am seeing a very strange issue in Chrome. Here's the page's header:

```
<html id="html" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" manifest="Portal/CacheManifestHandler.ashx">
```

Here are the manifest contents captured from fiddler:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/cache-manifest; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 20 Apr 2012 15:56:20 GMT
Content-Length: 56

CACHE MANIFEST
NETWORK:
*
#Timestamp: 634705337615835020
```

I have one particular script on the page's header inside  tag that is generated dynamically on server. Here are the contents returned for that script tag the first time user accesses the page:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 20 Apr 2012 15:36:33 GMT
Content-Length: 74

document.location='/Portal/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fPortal%2fDefault.aspx';
```

You can see neither the script is in Cache-manifest, nor its headers allow browser (Chrome) to cache it.
Still when I subsequently open the same page in browser, Chrome loads the page from cache-manifest, which is okay.
However surprisingly it loads the <script> also from cache. I can verify it as my server breakpoints are not hit, nor does Fiddler show a request for this <script>. The network is not down and the server is accessible (this should not have made a difference because Chrome was asked to not cache this <script> anyways).

Is this the expected behavior? Shouldn't Chrome have requested the <script> again from server even when its containing page was loaded from manifest cache.

Chrome's chrome://appcache-internals also shows only 2 urls in the cache which again is fine, why then it loads the <script> from cache and not the server
[image: Chrome's chrome://appcache-internals also shows only 2 urls in the cache which again is fine, why then it loads the <script> from cache and not the server]

Comment: have you tried setting the target page setting explicitly rather using *??

Comment: can you show how you are including the script in the master page?

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue, our resolution was to stick a * in the network section of our app.manifest so our Network section looked like

NETWORK:
*

I'm now digging to see if that's really "by design" for Google or just plain wrong.

Comment: Thanks for replying Josh. Unfortunately we dumped the idea of using Cache Manifest for our application, and I would no longer be able to test this out.